# How can I store different values using same input box using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the same **inputbox** for entering different values so each time when the values is entered i should store the value and display to the user .`<input type="text" onChange={e => this.addPrice('input1', e.target.value)} />`
this is placed inside the modal so whenever the modal popup is open use will enter the value

Comment: Can you add some more code making the question more clear? Right now it says you are using the same input box. But there is no mention of code showing where you are using it.

Comment: Does the user press a button (or perform another action) to store the value? Currently the `this.addPrice` in the `onChange` will be triggered for every character added to the input

Comment: addPrice=(input, value)=>{this.setState({amount:value}) how can i store the different  value entered in a same array or how to differentiate the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the same input box to add values to a single array, there will most likely have to be a secondary action (like pressing a button) that the user takes to indicate when to store the current value.

```
state = {
  currentValue: '',
  prices: [],
}

onChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ currentValue: event.target.value })
}

addPrice = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    prices: [...prevState.prices, this.state.currentValue]
  }))
}

...

<input type='text' onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.currentValue} />
<button onClick={this.addPrice}>Add Price</button>
```

Edit: You can store anything in the `prices` array. If you want key-value pairs then store objects like:

```
addPrice = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    prices: [...prevState.prices, {amount: this.state.currentValue}]
  }))
}
```

Comment: then while opening the input box again will result with the display of previous values since we are using value={this.state.currentValue}

Comment: You can add a method to clear the `currentValue` upon opening or closing the input box.

Comment: well said one more question can i set any key for the value while storing in an array like [key:'',value:'']

Comment: You can store whatever you want in the array, but it sounds like you want to store objects. I'll update the answer to address that.